# How to change class of focused contenteditable element on button click using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable, classname

I am trying to change class of an element located in `contenteditable` div

My current code is :

```
<button>swap class</button>
<div contenteditable="true">
    <h1 class="line-height-1">Your Headline Here</h1>
</div>    
<div contenteditable="true">
    <h1 class="line-height-1">Your Headline Here</h1>
</div>
```

I want to replace the class `.line-height-1` to another **for currently selected editable div** when clicking on button.

Can anyone Help ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click on button, focused element does blured. You need to store focused element in variable and change it on button click. After button click make it focused.

```js
var element;
$("div[contenteditable]").focus(function(){
    element = this;
});
$("button").click(function(){
    $(element).focus().find("h1").removeClass("line-height-1").addClass("newClass");
});
```

```css
.line-height-1 { color: red }
.newClass { color: blue }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>swap class</button>
<div contenteditable="true">
  <h1 class="line-height-1">Your Headline Here</h1>
</div>
<div contenteditable="true">
  <h1 class="line-height-1">Your Headline Here</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: This does not change the actual contenteditable html to have that class.  It only changes the DOM to have that class.